# jQuery errors "x.ready.promise is not a function" and "Modernizr.prefixed is not a function" / jQuery.noConflict

Tags: jquery, wordpress

When i use jQuery (1.10.2) with jQuery.noConflict(); My scripts give errors like: 
**TypeError: $ is not a function** for b.e. `$(window).load(function(){` or `$(document).ready(function() {`
When i turn noConflict off i got these errors: "**x.ready.promise is not a function**" and "**Modernizr.prefixed is not a function**"

The first error i understand? Who can explain the error with noConflict off? And tell me how to fix this.

I try to add:

```
    $.Deferred(function( defer ) {
    $( defer.resolve );
    $.ready.promise = defer.promise;
});
```

As suggest here: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12946

I came across this problem when upgrading a website to WordPress 3.6

Answer (score 1):

replace $ with jQuery if you have small amout of scripts.. 
or wrap them in:

```
    (function ($, window, document) { //code }(jQuery, window, document));
```

or

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() { //code });
```

or

```
    (function(window, undefined) {
    'use strict';
    //code
    })(this);
```